# How make property visible in InterfaceBuilder (Xcode)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I've created a protocol `CustomComponentDataSource` for delivering data to `CustomComponent`.

```
@protocol CustomComponentDataSource <NSObject>
- (NSUInteger)numberOfBlocksInView:(CustomComponent *)customComponent;
...
@end

@interface CustomComponent : NSView
...
@property id <CustomComponentDataSource> dataSource;
...
@end
```

Is it possible to make this `dataSource` property visibile and ready to be linked in XCode Interface Bulder??

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare it as an [`IBOutlet`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Outlets/Outlets.html):

```
@property IBOutlet id <CustomComponentDataSource> dataSource;
```